# getting RPM file location in the spec file

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am building an RPM file, during installation of the RPM i need to get the path of the .rpm file 
`echo $PWD` will return - '/'
`echo %(pwd)` will return the path to the location of the RPM build

to explain further
lets assume that i am producing A.rpm file, when deploying on a remote system i want to put on the remote system to files

A.rpm
argument.txt

in the %pre section i want to read the argument.txt file
i.e. something of the sort

```
if [ ! -f [what to put here]/argument.txt ]; then
 do something
fi
```

- the rpm file location is unknown during buildtime
- the argument file is guaranteed to be placed alongside the rpm

How can  I achieve this? is there a macro which i am unaware of?

Thanks in advance for any help,

Answer (score 2):

`%pre` is executed **before** installing package. Therefore you cannot access the content of the package. You may do that in `%post` and then it is in normal path (its destination).

Comment: well, thats not really the issue... the file that I need comes from a different place (not packed within the package). I do know that the file should be located alongside the package file. I need to find the location of the package. i.e. some macro with the fullpath of the package file on the device
there is also a section that verifies the file existance, if its not present the package should not be installed